# Is it possible to restart program from a user input?

Tags: java, restart

I'm currently doing a program, and I have arrived to a small problem.
I want to ask the user whether or not he would like to try again the application after he has completed it once.
If he says yes, I'd like to go back to the top of the program at a specific line.
Is it possible? thank you.

Comment: yes. use a `while loop`

Comment: and I'd like it to ask again once he has completed it twice and so on.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to use the while loop for this problem?

Comment: Yes. Use a while loop.

Comment: Would i have to put the whole program into a while loop..?

Comment: [While loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). Whatever code you want to be repeated, place it under a loop

Answer (score 1):

```
DO{
    // INSTRUCTIONS
    // ASK THE USER IF HÉ WANTS TO CONTINUE.
    // IF NOT, USE A BREAK TO SHUT OFF THE PROGRAM
} WHILE (TRUE);
```

Comment: why not make the condition a `boolean` variable, and then change the value based on user input inside the loop?

Comment: Both are acceptable but with THE break, we have one less test